# else if vs elif in python, are they equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

can we replace elif with else if in python?
is the following equal?

```
if (x>y):
    print("X")
else: if (x<y):
    print("Y")
```

vs:

```
if (x>y):
    print("X")
elif:
    print("Y")
```

Comment: Well, as is, the first one is invalid syntax…

Comment: @deceze so is 2nd one. `elif` without condition.

Comment: Ask yourself: What happens if `x == y`? (Assuming you corrected the code in the way I think it was intended to be)

Comment: @Matthias Assuming that OP corrected the indentation of the first and the `elif x < y` of the second, they would behave identically, and they may or may not be as expected with regards to the `==` case…

Comment: I thought the second example should have had an `else` and the first one was a nested `if`. But since the asker did a hit-and-run we'll never know.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the invalid syntax is a typo, the big benefit of `elif` vs having an `else` statement with a nested `if` is indentation. Each time you go into a nested `if` you'll need to indent again, which will destroy readability. On the other hand by using `elif` you'll be able to have all the different code paths on the same level of indentation.

Here is an example.

```
if a:
    A()
else:
    if b:
        B()
    else:
        if c:
            C()
```

As you can see, this is kind of confusing. Here is the `elif` based example.

```
if a:
    A()
elif b:
    B()
elif c:
    C()
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `else: if (x<y):` is a `SyntaxError`, the answer is no. You could nest an `if` inside an `else` block, but why would you when `elif` (with an actual condition, which you forgot) can avoid unnecessary nesting?

Answer (score 2):

The latter is the pythonic way of using the if/elif statements.

Nesting, the less the better!

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same but the proper way of write it is the second one.